# Proposition 7.4 of Euclid's Elements

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

Here is an online version of Book 7 of *Elements* where the following definitions and proposition can be found: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html

**Note:** In his books on number theory, Euclid uses the word "measures" in place of "divides".

**Definitions:**

> 1. A unit is that by virtue of which each of the things that exist is called one.
> 2. A number is a multitude composed of units. (Thus, a number is a positive integer greater than one.)
> 3. A number is a part of a(nother) number, the less of the greater, when it measures the greater;
> 4. But (the lesser is) parts (of the greater) when it does not measure it.

**Proposition 7.4 says:**

> Any number is either a part or parts of any (other) number, the less of the
>   greater.

Euclid gives a somewhat long proof of this but isn't it obvious? If $a<b$, $a$ either measures $b$ or doesn't measure $b$. Thus, $a$ is either a part or parts of $b$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, the "Guide" in your link seems to comment on this very issue.

Comment: Since it took me a bit to find it, here's the link: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Book VII you'll [find](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/defVII3.html)

> Definitions 3–5
>
> 3. A number is a part of a number, the less of the greater, when it measures the greater;
> 4. But parts when it does not measure it.
> 5. The greater number is a multiple of the less when it is measured by the less.

When you read these definitions it appears that Euclid's definition is an axiomatic statement:

$\quad$ IF $a \lt b$ THEN $[ \,a \text{ is a part of } b\,] \text{ xor } [\,a \text{ is parts of } b\,]$.

In the guide to the above definitions you'll find

> There is one more difficulty with this definition. It seems obvious
>   that when one number $a =mu$ is less than another $b =nu$, then in all
>   cases $a$ would be parts of $b$, namely $a$ consists of $m \text{ one-}n^\text{th}$ parts of
>   $b$. Yet, the proposition VII.4 has a proof to show that $a$ is either a
>   part or parts of $b$. The reason is that the desired parts should be in
>   lowest terms. For our example, where $a = 4u$ and $b = 6u$, it isn’t
>   enough to say that $a$ is 4 one-sixth parts of $b$; what’s needed is that
>   $a$ is $2$ one-third parts of $b$.

So I think Euclid felt the need for an $\text{XOR}$ algorithm that could decide the matter for any two distinct numbers. Lurking behind this is that he won't be defining rational numbers as an equivalence relation on a set - he needs to calculate a  a canonical representation/idea/concept.

Euclid's logic of not regarding $1$ as a number also plays a part in this. My guess is that an attempt was being made to 'compartmentalize' concepts and to avoid trivial statements. For Euclid the number, say five, is a multitude of units. He doesn't want to also say that one is a part of five.

It is interesting how liberating the logic becomes, when, in modern mathematical treatments we don't ignore or shortchange the *trivial* numbers $1$ or $0$. Euclid would certainly be amazed to see how much things open up once we can all agree on the existence of the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's proof isn't much longer than that.  He breaks things into three cases.  Assuming that $a<b$ are positive integers:

- If $a\mid b$, then $a$ is a part of $b$ (e.g. $2$ is a part of $4$)
- If $(a,b)=1$, then $a$ are parts of $b$ (e.g. $3$ are parts of $5$)
- If $(a,b)>1$ but $a\not\mid b$, then $a$ are parts of $b$ (e.g. $4$ are parts of $6$)

Yes, today we would merge those last two cases without a second thought.  But it seems from [the commentary](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/defVII1.html) that there was a philosophical squabble at the time over whether $1$ was a proper number, so Euclid evidently felt it was worth a separate case.

---

Your question asked "What am I missing?"  TBH, I don't know.  Was this it?